# Create a new partition for /home

Tags: partitioning, home-directory

Currently I have `/` in `/sda1`, which has 732.3GB.

All I want to do is separate `/home` in a new partition, so that later on I can install Ubuntu 16.04 while preserving the data in `/home`.

[image]

The 732.3GB partition has 664.4GB being used, so I can't create a new parition for `/home` using Gparted, I have to somehow divide the existing partition into 2, with the new one being exclusively `/home`.

I don't how to explain it better, but I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is to boot from live USB/DVD of Ubuntu and use Gparted from the live USB to shrink the existing / partition.

However, you have too much data to shrink the partition and create empty space. You will need an external hard drive to move some of the data from /home. Then you will be able to shrink /, create new partition and move the /home to the new partition.

The details are at

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Hope this helps

Comment: that is exactly the problem, I'm only trying to find how to do this because I don't have and external hard drive (I had one but I dropped it and it broke)

Comment: Save your money till you can buy two external hard drives. Use one to back up all the data, and use the second for the moving the home.